# Could not read entry ... from cache taskArtifacts.bin

Tags: android-studio, gradle

After my mac crashed I got the error message on every sync:

> Error:Could not read entry ':randomModuleName:compileReleaseShaders'
>   from cache taskArtifacts.bin
>   (/Users/me/development/projectname/.gradle/2.10/taskArtifacts/taskArtifacts.bin).
>   > [Ljava.lanava.lang.; serializable and externalizable flags conflict

I already cleaned the caches of Android Studio and cleared the project, without success.

What should I try to make my project working again?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After playing around I just deleted my `.gradle` directory in the project root and Android Studio started working again.

Comment: Thank you. this did it for me.